# SQL Server : how to remove consecutive duplicate words in a string

Tags: sql-server, string

Currently I have a dynamic query, generated in the stored procedure, that has a bug. Somehow there is a consecutive duplicate 'AND' generated in it.

Wondering if there is a way to delete the CONSECUTIVE DUPLICATE 'AND' from the dynamic query string.

For eg:

```
var str = 'Select * from employee A where A.age > 30 AND AND A.role = ''developer'''
```

**Update**

The replace as suggested below doesnt work
Please see the below query:

```
 DECLARE 
      @str NVARCHAR(MAX)



      SET @str  = 'fasdf asdfasf asfasdfasafsdf AND       AND     asdfasdfasd AND dfasdfa'


  SET @str = REPLACE(@str, 'AND AND', 'AND')

  PRINT @str
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fix the **actual bug** (the core issue) instead of "patching" a fix on top of a wrong result!

Comment: How this query is generating.??

Comment: I agree @Marc_s , it is not correct to manage a problem by adding a patch on it. Please check the place where dynamic SQL is created. You can review http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx where dynamic SQL query is build and "WHERE" and "AND" clauses are handled with care.

Comment: FINALLY....solved the stinking problem with 3 `SQL Functions`. I wish I was a bit more disciplined when it comes to troubleshooting finesse problems (or learn to take breaks when I am hitting my head for a while), but after taking a break for a while I solved the puzzle. The issue has to do with how `REPLACE` works in the query. See my reinstated post. Candidly, I still think I like Salmon's version for portability reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RemoveConsecutiveDuplicateTokens]    Script Date: 30/06/2016 09:30:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[RemoveConsecutiveDuplicateTokens] 
@instr   varchar(max) ,
@outstr varchar(max) OUTPUT
as
declare @workstr  varchar(max) = ltrim(@instr),
        @newstr   varchar(max),
        @oldtoken varchar(max),
        @newtoken varchar(max)

while   @workstr is not null
begin
    if @oldtoken is null 
        begin
        set @oldtoken = SUBSTRING(@workstr,1,charindex(' ',@workstr))
        set @workstr =  ltrim(Stuff(@workstr, CharIndex(@oldtoken,@workstr), Len(@oldtoken), ''))
        set @newstr = @oldtoken +  ' '
        end
    set @newtoken = SUBSTRING(@workstr,1,charindex(' ',@workstr))

    if @newtoken <> @oldtoken
        begin
            if  @newtoken <> char(39)
                begin
                    set @oldtoken = @newtoken
                    set @newstr = @newstr + @newtoken + ' '
                    set @workstr =  ltrim(Stuff(@workstr, CharIndex(@newtoken,@workstr), Len(@newtoken), ''))
                end
        end
    else 
        begin
            set @workstr =  ltrim(Stuff(@workstr, CharIndex(@newtoken,@workstr), Len(@newtoken), ''))
        end

    if  charindex(' ',@workstr) = 0 
        break
end 
set @newtoken = SUBSTRING(@workstr,1,len(@workstr))
    if @newtoken <> @oldtoken
        begin
            if  @newtoken <> char(39)
                begin
                    set @oldtoken = @newtoken
                    set @newstr = @newstr + @newtoken + ' '
                    set @workstr =  ltrim(Stuff(@workstr, CharIndex(@newtoken,@workstr), Len(@newtoken), ''))
                end
        end
    else 
        begin
            set @workstr =  ltrim(Stuff(@workstr, CharIndex(@newtoken,@workstr), Len(@newtoken), ''))
        end
select @outstr = @newstr

return
```

Comment: +1 I was going to do something similar, but your answer is pretty complete. It solves the entire SP string, provided there are no intentional duplicates...though with your code it is fairly simple to tinker with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **you are doing it wrong. Fix the logic** that generates this incorrect sql.

But for research/learning purposes, this is how you do.

```
REPLACE ( str , 'AND AND' , 'AND')
```

Comment: I know its wrong , and its only to be used if nothing else works...however the number of spaces , new lines between the 2 'AND'  is variable , meaning there could be extra spaces or even new lines, so the above wouldnt work right away

Comment: Well i found the source of the error and corrected it , just as suggested by darkknight and others, but for the sake of this post , i will pick this as the answer , although others are right too , just that this answer is the shortest working solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesnt work . @clifton_h I dont think sql server ignores the extra spaces like you said. Please see the example in the updated post

Comment: @clifton_h I did not mean the outcome of a query , rather the outcome of the replace , please try the sample that i posted and observe the print statement , it does nothing to remove the extra 'AND', which is the original issue.

Comment: @MR.K LOL, I need to stop reading things through my mobile phone at night, sometimes it gets a bit hazy. I am an idiot. Yes, it is failing since there are CHAR(32) characters in between. REPLACE and all functions are affected by the actual characters in the string. Hang on, let me try to answer this one to make up

Answer (score 1):

I forgot how much I dislike SUBSTRING, but then that has been my struggle to read `<starting_position>` as truly the position the value **begins with**.

However, the real beast was how string manipulations are implemented in SQL Server under the context of the `@@TRANCOUNT`.

- Consider the statement

  `PRINT QUOTE_NAME(REPLACE('My____Table', '__', '_'))`

We wish to use proper naming standards, but the function returns:

```
`[My__Table]`
```

Why? Because `REPLACE` jumps ahead the length of the duplicates. To prove it, lets add one more '_' `CHAR(95)` and we get this in return:

```
`[My___Table]`
```

So then simply embedding this with a WHILE statement, for example, will be quite sufficient for our needs. *Note I replaced the spaces with '_' for readability*

```
    DECLARE @instr   varchar(max)
    SET @instr = 'SELECT * from employee A where A.age > 30 AND    AND A.role = ''developer'''

    DECLARE @workstr  varchar(max) = REPLACE(LTRIM(@instr), ' ', '_'),
    @tokenque VARCHAR(MAX),
    @newstr   INT = 0,
    @token varchar(max),
    @flag_break INT = 0

-- removes the extra "spaces"
    WHILE CHARINDEX('__', @workstr) <> 0
        BEGIN
        SET @workstr = REPLACE(@workstr, '__' , '_')
        END
    SET @tokenque = @workstr
    WHILE (CHARINDEX('_', @tokenque) <> 0)
    BEGIN
    SET @token = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, 1, CHARINDEX('_', @Tokenque) - 1 )
    IF @token <> '''' -- (') delimiter skipped
      BEGIN
      WHILE CHARINDEX(@token + '_' +  @token, @workstr) <> 0
        BEGIN
        SET @workstr = REPLACE(@workstr, @token + '_' + @token, @token)
        END
      SET @tokenque = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, LEN(@token) + 2, LEN(@tokenque) )
       END
    ELSE SET @tokenque = SUBSTRING(@tokenque, LEN(@token) + 2, LEN(@tokenque) )

    PRINT @tokenque --if you want to see the progression  
    END
PRINT REPLACE(@workstr, '_', ' ')
```

**RESULT:**

```
'SELECT * from employee A where A.age > 30 AND A.role = 'developer'
```

Comment: This was really easy to follow , i must say , Good work  breaking it down!

Comment: @Mr.K Thanks. I think I say I finally understand `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` properly. So thanks for helping me learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

use the REPLACE function and replace 'AND AND' by 'AND'. example

```
SELECT REPLACE('Select * from employee A where A.age > 30 AND AND A.role = ''developer'' ','AND AND','AND');
```